# ORACLE : Materialized view- change START WITH CLAUSE

Tags: oracle, view, materialized

I created a Materialized view using the following code:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW M_USER_HIERARCHY 

BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH TO_DATE('25-Aug-2009 10:34:24','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
NEXT SYSDATE + 1     
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 
SELECT   * FROM V_USER_HIERARCHY;
```

However, I want to be able to change the START WITH date AFTER this code has been executed.
I have been looking into the ALL_MVIEW_* tables but could not find where the setting for the START_DATE is.

Does anyone know how to change the START_WITH date of a Materialized View ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really quite straightforward.

```
SQL> create materialized view emp_data
  2  as select * from emp
  3  /

Materialized view created.

SQL> ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_data
  2     REFRESH COMPLETE
  3     START WITH TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 12/24
  4     NEXT SYSDATE+1
  5  /

Materialized view altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Indeed that was very easy !

Thx for the help